# importing hybrid package in react native/typescript/expo

Tags: typescript, expo, es6-modules, fp-ts

I'm trying to import the library [fp-ts-std](https://github.com/samhh/fp-ts-std) but my import fails.

The [readme](https://github.com/samhh/fp-ts-std#installation) refers to conditional exports, that is:
the library exports 2 versions. More thoroughly explained [here](https://www.the-guild.dev/blog/support-nodejs-esm).

- One for cjs in `fp-ts-std/dist/cjs`
- One for ES-modules in `fp-ts-std/dist/esm`

I can import my function from the specified sub-directory "fp-ts-std/dist/esm", however without typechecking, which defeats the purpose of the library. If i import from fp-ts-std/Record, typescript checks out but i get the error

> Unable to resolve module fp-ts-std/Record

I have tried setting moduleResolution in tsconfig to "node12" or "nodenext", however this flag isn't even available when I'm using the latest development version of typescript.

My project uses typescript, react native and expo.

1. How do i find out if my environment supports conditional imports?
2. Is there a solution?

**To replicate:**

```
npm i expo-cli -g
expo init hybrid-test-app
npm i fp-ts-std --save
```

In any file:

```
import {pick} from "fp-ts-std/Record";
pick(["hello"], {hello: "world"}
```

The resulting [package.json](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/templates/expo-template-blank-typescript/package.json). The [tsconfig](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/templates/expo-template-blank-typescript/tsconfig.json) inherits from [this file](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-module-scripts/tsconfig.base.json). I don't think these are the problem though, as i have seen working projects with identical tsconfig, but without expo.

Comment: You should provide an example code of your failing import, with your package.json & tsconfig.json. Narrow your case so people can help you easily.

Comment: I have updated the question as suggested